# How do I submit an app in iTunes AppStore that is only Spanish?

Tags: iphone, app-store, itunes, app-store-connect

I have an app to submit to the App store that is Spanish only (not English with a Spanish localization).  But it appears the only option is to submit in English then add the localization. Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

If by "submit in English" you're referring to the iTunes Connect languages, then yes, you have to enter the details in whatever your default language is (from what you said, it appears it is English) and then add the Spanish.

But note that iTunes languages have no relation to the app's languages. So if you only care about Spanish, you can enter everything in Spanish on the default language, regardless of what it is. These languages in iTunesConnect are only used by iTunes to choose, based on the country (store) that the user is in, which descriptions/keywords/etc to use.

Comment: Let me make sure I understand what you're saying.  So if the profile for the app says "English" in iTunes it is based on the country (store) that the we submitted the app under?  We wanted the app to be available everywhere but wanted to signify that all the content is in Spanish.  I thought we had to specify that it is a "Spanish" language app.  Can you clarify?  The app is Deficiencia de Nutrientes.  The description is in spanish.  But if a user is looking for only Spanish apps will this app show up in the search?

Comment: No, that's not it. The "languages" section displayed on iTunes next to your app reflects what the app itself supports (based your app's resources, e.g. the "es.lproj" directory, or alternatively the languages stated explicitly on your info.plist, which you normally won't need to have). That list of languages will be the same, regardless of which store users are looking at your app from. The iTunesConnect localizations are something else: those are used only for the app descriptions *on iTunes*, and the language that users actually get to see for those descriptions will depend on their store.

Comment: Also, if your app only supports spanish, in your info.plist you should probably state that the "native development language" is "es".

Answer (score 1):

In iTunesConnect, go to Manage Applications, Add New App.

Fill out the first few pages until it asks you about availability date and price tier.

At the bottom is a link to "specific stores". Click on this and select only the store you want the app to be available in.

Comment: @Indy said he wants to make the app available everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

During the submission process you add the Spanish localisation. Also, you should limit its availability to Spanish-speaking countries. The localisation is used based on the App Store locale.
Also, you can add the Spanish text into the English description. Lots of apps (German, Chinese, etc.) seem to be doing this for the UK App Store.